# Stop iff using a debugger

Tags: gdb, signals

I'd like to write an assert-style macro that stops only if I am running the program in a debugger. AFAIK, the only available debugger on my box is gdb, so I'll talk about that one.

The documentation for the SIGTRAP signal indicates that it is intended for pausing the debugger, so I should be able to put

```
if (!assertion) raise(SIGTRAP);
```

in my code. It works to break GDB at the right point, but just running this from the command line also halts the program, as both bash and zsh helpfully interpret the "trace/breakpoint trap" signal to mean that the program should halt entirely.

Are there any signals that GDB uses but which I can expect that everything else ignores? Or is there a method beyond signals to pause execution in GDB without disrupting non-debugger operation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Forking a child and trying to `ptrace` parent is a portable UNIX way to determine whether you are being `ptrace`d, or not, and you can then do `raise(signo)` *only* when being traced.

Note however, that this mechanism will *also* trigger if you are running under `strace` or `truss`, effectively making your program crash under them, which is probably undesirable.

A Linux-specific way that is easier to implement is to look in `/proc/self/status` for non-`0` `TracerPid`. This still has the same disadvantage as above.

Another Linux-specific way is to call `getppid`, then `readlink("/proc/$PARENT_PID/exe", ...)`, and see if that points to GDB.

Both Linux-specific examples assume that `/proc` is mounted, which is usually true, but doesn't have to be.

> Are there any signals that GDB uses but which I can expect that everything else ignores?

The `SIGWINCH` is usually ignored by non-terminal-handling programs. GDB will also ignore it, but you can make GDB stop on `SIGWINCH` by issuing this command:

```
(gdb) handle SIGWINCH stop print nopass
Signal        Stop  Print   Pass to program   Description
SIGWINCH      Yes   Yes     No                Window size changed
```

Answer (score 1):

The GDB documentation tells us:

> When GDB runs on a "Posix system" (such as GNU or Unix machines), it interfaces with the inferior via the `ptrace' system call.

On Linux systems a process can not be traced by more than one other process. If your program forks a child that tries to attach to its parent, that will fail if you already have gdb attached to it. Signalling this failure back to the parent can be done with an exit value.

Answer (score 0):

There is SIGCHLD, which is ignored by default. I think gdb is triggered by any signal, but possibly not by ignored ones. You can always write a signal handler for SIGUSR1, which does nothing (which is not the same as ignoring the signal: the program gets interrupted, it just returns immediately). Then you can send SIGUSR1, and while it would normally abort the program, it will now do nothing (because you told it to). For details about setting up a signal handler, see the documentation on `sigaction`.